# Cypress: How to spy a method called by a button click

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, cypress, cypress-component-test-runner

I'm using Vue3 + Vite + Cypress. Using Vue3 `script setup` SFC syntax. I have a component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button data-cy="testBtn" @click="btnClick()">
      Click
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
function btnClick():void {
  console.log('clicked');
}
</script>
```

How can I spy on `btnClick` so that I can assert that it has been called when I do `cy.get('[data-cy="testBtn"]').click();`?
I have tried:

```
describe('Test', () => {
  it.only(`Test`, () => {
    mount(TestComponent, {
      props: {
        device: TestComponent
      }
    });

    cy.vue().then((wrapper) => {
      const test = cy.spy(wrapper.vm, 'btnClick');
      cy.get('[data-cy="testBtn"]').click();
      expect(test).to.be.called;
    });
  });
});
```

but I get an error `Attempted to wrap undefined property btnClick as function`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug in `cy.spy()` when used with component test.

This "manual" spy worked for me

```js
it.only('', () => {
  mount(TestComponent)
    .then(() => {                  // wait for mount to complete

      // spy on click handler
      let called;
      const original = Cypress.vueWrapper.vm.btnClick
      Cypress.vueWrapper.vm.btnClick = () => {
        called = true
        original()
      }

      cy.get('[data-cy="testBtn"]').click()
        .then(() => expect(called).to.eq(true))
    })
});
```